# How to configure Tomcat SSLHostConfig correctly?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, ssl-certificate

I was following this tutorial to enable ssl in tomcat: https://medium.com/@raupach/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-with-tomcat-3db8a469e3d2

Altough tomcat is running at the end, i can not access https, says *unable to connect*. So i checked the logs and i got:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SSLHostConfig attribute certificateFile must be defined when using an SSL connector
```

, but my certificateFile is defined as you can see:

```
<Connector port="443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    maxThreads="100"
    compression="on"
    scheme="https"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    secure="true"
    SSLVerifyClient="none"
    SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2"
    defaultSSLHostConfigName="test.test">
    <SSLHostConfig hostName="test.test">
        <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem" certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem" certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

these files are present in conf/

tomcat 9 docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html section SSLHostConfig and Certificate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use a mix of new (since Tomcat 8.5) and deprecated attributes (cf. [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_Connector_-_APR/Native_(deprecated))). The effect of setting, e.g. `SSLProtocol` is the creation of a second `<SSLHostConfig>` with hostname `_default_`. That is the element that the error message is referring to.

You should replace the obsolete tags (`SSLVerifyClient` and `SSLProtocol`) with their current counterparts (or omit them if you want the default value):

```xml
<Connector port="443"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="100"
           compression="on"
           scheme="https"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           secure="true"
           defaultSSLHostConfigName="test.test">
    <SSLHostConfig hostName="test.test"
                   protocols="TLSv1.2">
        <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
                     certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

**Remark:** The attributes you used where specific to the APR connector. If that choice was intentional, you should change the protocol to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol`.

Comment: What would this look like if you were configuring in java? Ala

Comment: `startup.sh` has a `-generateCode <path_to_a_directory` command line argument. You can use it to convert any configuration into code.

Answer (score 0):

To manually manage ciphers you can add `ciphers` as below:

```
<SSLHostConfig ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
                        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
             protocols="TLSv1.2">
```