# Tomcat8 error SSLHostConfig attribute certificateFile must be defined when using an SSL connector

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

**This is my configuration information**

```
      <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               useServerCipherSuitesOrder="true" clientAuth="want"
               defaultSSLHostConfigName="test.com"
                >
        <SSLHostConfig hostName="test.com"  truststoreFile="/opt/security/client_trust.jks"
                       truststorePassword="test" sslProtocol="TLS" protocols="TLSv1.2"
                       ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                                TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384">
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/opt/security/keystore.jks"
                         certificateKeystorePassword="test" certificateKeyAlias="tomcat"
                         />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

**Tomcat error info**

```
08-Dec-2021 11:46:41.361 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1076)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:843)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SSLHostConfig attribute certificateFile must be defined when using an SSL connector
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:100)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:72)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:246)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1161)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:599)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:80)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1074)
                ... 13 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: SSLHostConfig attribute certificateFile must be defined when using an SSL connector
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:309)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:244)
                at org.apach
```

I don't understand why the error is reported.
So the correct configuration should be?
The class Http11NioProtocol cannot be replaced.
\n
It's success When I not use attribute  SSLHostConfig.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="/opt/security/keystore.jks"
               keystorePass="test" keyAlias="tomcat"
               sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
               ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
               useServerCipherSuitesOrder="true"
               truststoreFile="/opt/security/client_trust.jks"
               truststorePass="test" clientAuth="want" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Tomcat SSLHostConfig correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258040/how-to-configure-tomcat-sslhostconfig-correctly)

Comment: `useServerCipherSuitesOrder` is a deprecated attriibute (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_Connector_-_NIO_and_NIO2_(deprecated))), hence the above mentioned answer applies. Use `honorCipherOrder` on the `SSLHostConfig` element instead. I assume you are using Tomcat 8.5.

Comment: I don't see any difference between me and him. Thank you for your advice